# NSArray -> Find closest value - fastest way

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

Lets say I've got an ordered `NSArray` of `NSNumbers`:

```
2, 4, 8, 15, 16, 20 // for simplicity let's treat it as array of int's instead of NSNumbers
```

Now I need to find closest index to let's say `value == 19`.

```
searchValue = 19;
minIndex = 0;
maxIndex = array.count - 1;
currentIndex = (int)floorf(maxIndex / 2.f);

while (maxIndex - minIndex == 1) {
    if (array[currentIndex] < searchValue) { // go right
        minIndex = currentIndex;
    } else if (array[currentIndex] > searchValue) { // go left
        maxIndex = currentIndex;
    } else { // exact value, rather low probability of happening
        return currentIndex;
    }

    currentIndex = (int)floorf((maxIndex - minIndex) / 2.f);
}

// let's check values around, who has smaller difference
int leftDifference = (currentIndex - 1 >= 0) ? abs(array[currentIndex - 1] - searchValue) : INT_MAX;
int rightDifference = (currentIndex + 1 < array.count) ? abs(array[currentIndex + 1] - searchValue) : INT_MAX;
int centralDifference = abs(array[currentIndex] - searchValue);
if (leftDifference < rightDifference && leftDifference < centralDifference) {
    return currentIndex - 1;
} else if () {
    return currentIndex + 1;
} else {
    return currentIndex;
}
```

This is the fastest way I can imagine, maybe someone has different idea? How can I improve the algorithm?

I've took a look into eg[SOF question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318733/get-closest-value-to-a-number-in-array), but it search for value not index and does it by browsing all values. In case of index, we don't have to browse full array.

Comment: Why do you need to optimise this particular operation? I suggest that rather than optimising the search you would be better using faster container class. Even if you inspect every element the search is O(n)

Comment: @RogerNolan I already have an array containing a lot of objects of my custom class. Between others, it also have these values I want to perform search on. I don't want to copy all of them or even selected values as it will take both time and memory. To change container class I'd need to change almost whole application, what is impossible for time given to complete the task. I need to optimise it, as the algorithm will be called every second (timer...).

Comment: Looks ripe for a [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets assume you have an array of NSNumbers:

```
NSArray *array = @[@(2), @(4), @(8), @(15), @(16), @(20)];
```

And you are looking for `myValue` as below:

```
NSNumber *myValue = @(17);
```

Use `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator` method to find the nearest index of array to you value. Binary search has O(log n) performance so is pretty fast.

```
NSInteger searchIndex = MIN([array indexOfObject: myValue inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, array.count)
                                   options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual | NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                           usingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSNumber *obj1, NSNumber *obj2) {
                               return [obj1 compare:obj2];
                           }], [array count] - 1);
```

Then check if exists a number closest to yours `myValue` on the `searchIndex - 1` index:

```
if (searchIndex > 0) {
    CGFloat leftHandDiff = ABS(((NSNumber *)array[searchIndex - 1]).floatValue - myValue.floatValue);
    CGFloat rightHandDiff = ABS(((NSNumber *)array[searchIndex]).floatValue - myValue.floatValue);

    if (leftHandDiff == rightHandDiff) {
        //here you can add behaviour when your value is in the middle of range
        NSLog(@"given value is in the middle");
    } else if (leftHandDiff < rightHandDiff) {
        searchIndex--;
    }
}

NSLog(@"The nearest value to %f is %d in array at index %d", myValue.floatValue, array[searchIndex], searchIndex);
```

and voila! Now you now the closest value to `myValue`.

**Remember** that your `array` has to be sorted ascending to make this trick.

Comment: I originally wrote a UICollectionViewLayout drag/drop engine that supported snapping - I wrote it very complex. With this answer, I thought about caching some x/y values in the preparation methods - and in the update position function i'm now using your searchIndex trick to check against these values and the cell frame origin. Works insanely well. Thank you so much! 