# Get all nearest points in array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, math

I'v two dimensional array, am storing some points in it in order to get the nearest two points e.g :
*"(-1, 3), (-1, -1), (1, 1), (2, 0.5) , (2, -1) , (3, 3) ,(4, 2) ,(4, 0.5)"*
The result is : *"(1.0, 1.0) and (2.0, 0.5)"*
 And that worked very-well:

```
   Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of points");
    int numberOfPoints = scanner.nextInt();

    //setting number of rows, number of column is unable to change
    double[][] points = new double[numberOfPoints][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        points[i][0] = scanner.nextDouble();
        points[i][1] = scanner.nextDouble();
    }

    int point1 = 0, point2 = 1;
    double shortestDistance = distance(points[point1][0], points[point1][1],
            points[point2][0], points[point2][1]);

    //get shortest distance
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
            double distance = distance(points[i][0], points[i][1],
                    points[j][0], points[j][1]);

            if (shortestDistance > distance) {

                point1 = i;
                point2 = j;
                shortestDistance = distance;
            }

        }
    }

    System.out.println("The closest two points is" +
            "(" + points[point1][0] + ", " + points[point1][1] + ") and (" +
            points[point2][0] + ", " + points[point2][1] + ")");

}

public static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return Math.sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1));
}
```

Am trying to get all nearest points not only two points.

I'v tried to get it by this way, but it doesn't cover all cases and doesn't display all points:

```
for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < points.length; j++) {
            if (distance(points[i][0], points[i][1],
                    points[j][0], points[j][1]) == shortestDistance)
                System.out.println("The closest two points are " +
                        "(" + points[i][0] + ", " + points[i][1] + ") and (" +
                        points[j][0] + ", " + points[j][1] + ")");
        }
    }
```

Also I'v tried to initialize new array and store distance into it then sort it, but it's fail.

How i can display all nearest points?

Note:

I didn't find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318733/get-closest-value-to-a-number-in-array) useful for me.

Comment: *"but it doesn't cover all cases"* In what way doesn't it cover all cases? Please give example.

Comment: @Andreas the above input just output two points instead of four.

Comment: What 4 points? There are no other points that are 1.118033988749895 apart.

Comment: To prove it, [here](https://ideone.com/8Y2WzA) is code to print a list of all distances between all pairs of points, sorted by distance. Reversed pairs are not compared, since the distance between `(1.0, 1.0)` and `(2.0, 0.5)` is of course the same as the distance between `(2.0, 0.5)` and `(1.0, 1.0)`. As you can see, there is only one pair of points that are `1.118033988749895` apart.

Comment: @Andreas am afraid that you go far a way from the issue core, every (x, y) should have nearest another (x, y), i input 4 pairs the output should nearest 4 pairs, (**that's my issue**).

What you'v missed understand?

Comment: No, you've given 8 points, not 4 pairs of points. If you truly only want to compare 4 pairs, not the full 28 possible combinations of pairs from 8 points, then your code is way off to begin with, because your code does 28 distance calculations. Nowhere in question text or question code does it say that you have 4 pairs. Both text and code processes 8 points, and that is exactly what [my code](https://ideone.com/8Y2WzA) does too.

Comment: @Andreas Let it 8 points (not 4 pairs), the out put should be 8 points since i need to display all points.

Such that e.g : (-1, 3), (-1, -1) & (1, 1), (2, 0.5) & 2, -1) , (3, 3) & (4, 2) ,(4, 0.5).

Comment: @Andreas just think more in math,

Comment: So you mean that when you've found the 2 points that are closest to each other (`(1.0, 1.0) - (2.0, 0.5)`), you want to eliminate those then find the next "pair" that are *now* closest to each other (`(3.0, 3.0) - (4.0, 2.0)`), then repeat (`(2.0, -1.0) - (4.0, 0.5)`), and finally get last remaining pair (`(-1.0, 3.0) - (-1.0, -1.0)`)? If so, then you should update question and actually **say that**, because there is no way I would ever get that from reading the question as it is now.

Comment: @Andreas exactly

Comment: @Andreas `because there is no way I would ever get that from reading the question as it is now` I think OP did.

Comment: What if there are 3 points that are equally closest at the same time, e.g. like pairs `(2.0, 0.5) - (3.0, 3.0)` and `(3.0, 3.0) - (4.0, 0.5)` are both `2.692582403567252` apart?

Comment: @Andreas I may add a condition for that, thanks.

Comment: If by "OP did" you're referring to answer by Joop Eggen, then his code doesn't do that. It also only prints one pair. That comment was confusing, since in a comment to the question, "OP" refers to you, since you *are* the "Original Poster" of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The following [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046642/get-all-nearest-points-in-array?noredirect=1#comment81041655_47046642) clarifies the actual goal of the question:

> So you mean that when you've found the 2 points that are closest to each other (`(1.0, 1.0) - (2.0, 0.5)`), you want to eliminate those then find the next "pair" that are *now* closest to each other (`(3.0, 3.0) - (4.0, 2.0)`), then repeat (`(2.0, -1.0) - (4.0, 0.5)`), and finally get last remaining pair (`(-1.0, 3.0) - (-1.0, -1.0)`)?

To do that, you should first create a `Point` class, so you can easily keep track of points that have already been used. You could use [`java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html) if you don't want to write your own.

You should also create a class for tracking pairs of points, so you can easily sort the pairs by distance. It can be named anything, but I named it `Distance` below.

Now the logic is that you create a list of all the possible `Distance` objects, i.e. pairs of points. You then sort it by distance.

The first list element is now the pair that is nearest to each other. You then iterate the list to find the next pair of points that are nearest, skipping any that use points already used.

If more than one pair are equally "nearest", the logic below will just pick one of them. You can change that behavior once you define what should actually happen in that scenario.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] pointValues = { {-1, 3}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, {2, 0.5}, {2, -1}, {3, 3}, {4, 2}, {4, 0.5} };

    Point[] points = new Point[pointValues.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        points[i] = new Point(pointValues[i][0], pointValues[i][1]);

    List<Distance> distances = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++)
            distances.add(new Distance(points[i], points[j]));
    Collections.sort(distances);

    Set<Point> used = new HashSet<>();
    for (Distance distance : distances) {
        if (! used.contains(distance.getPoint1()) && ! used.contains(distance.getPoint2())) {
            System.out.println(distance);
            used.add(distance.getPoint1());
            used.add(distance.getPoint2());
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public final class Point {
    private final double x;
    private final double y;
    public Point(double x, double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
    public double getX() {
        return this.x;
    }
    public double getY() {
        return this.y;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Double.hashCode(this.x) * 31 + Double.hashCode(this.y);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (! (obj instanceof Point))
            return false;
        Point that = (Point) obj;
        return (Double.doubleToLongBits(this.x) == Double.doubleToLongBits(that.x)
             && Double.doubleToLongBits(this.y) == Double.doubleToLongBits(that.y));
    }
}
```

```java
public final class Distance implements Comparable<Distance> {
    private final Point  p1;
    private final Point  p2;
    private final double distance;
    public Distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;
        this.distance = Math.hypot(p2.getX() - p1.getX(), p2.getY() - p1.getY());
    }
    public Point getPoint1() {
        return this.p1;
    }
    public Point getPoint2() {
        return this.p2;
    }
    public double getDistance() {
        return this.distance;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%-12s - %-12s: %s", this.p1, this.p2, this.distance);
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Distance that) {
        return Double.compare(this.distance, that.distance);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
(1.0, 1.0)   - (2.0, 0.5)  : 1.118033988749895
(3.0, 3.0)   - (4.0, 2.0)  : 1.4142135623730951
(2.0, -1.0)  - (4.0, 0.5)  : 2.5
(-1.0, 3.0)  - (-1.0, -1.0): 4.0
```

Answer (score -1):

First a optimizing trick: instead of distance, use its square (dropping taking the root).

```
public static double distance2(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return (x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1);
}
```

Taking all nearest points one needs to maintain a list of (i, j).

```
List<int[]> nearestPointIndices = new ArrayList<>();
double shortestDistance2 = Double.MAX_VALUE;

for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < points.length; j++) {
        double distance2 = distance2(points[i][0], points[i][1],
                points[j][0], points[j][1]);

        if (shortestDistance2 >= distance2) {
            if (shortestDistance2 > distance2) {
                nearestPointIndices.clear();
                shortestDistance2 = distance2;
            }
            nearestPointIndices.add(new int[] { i, j });
        }
    }
}
```

That is one collects a list of nearest points upto (i, j) and
either clears that list on a more near point, or on the same near point add to the list.

---

Also worth mentioning is another the function of the Math class like sqrt:

```
public static double distance(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return Math.hypot((x2 - x1), (y2 - y1)); // Hypotenuse sqrt(a² + b²).
}
```

Comment: In what way does any of this address the point of the question, i.e. OP's mistaken belief that there is more than one pair of points with the same "shortest" distance? *Reference:* "I'v tried to get it by this way, but it **doesn't cover all cases** and **doesn't display all points**", with followup in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47046642/get-all-nearest-points-in-array?noredirect=1#comment81041004_47046642): "the above input just output two points instead of **four**". There is only one nearest *pair* of points.

Comment: @Andreas there could be two pair of points with the same minimal distance, say 1 for (2, 0)-(2, 1) and (4, 3)-(5, 3). I have not manually looked in the OPs data, nor run the code on the data. The OPs code indeed only gives two points. Mine would not.

Comment: @Andreas I just now saw the comment track involved. What can I say? I still hope my answer is good for something, even if it is just `Math.hypot` to calculate a distance.

Comment: There is only one pair, but you're right, there could be more than one with shortest distance, and the code in the question would have printed all of them (including flipped pairs, doubling output). Your code is *optimized*, but doing the full work in one iteration, while question code uses one iteration to find the shortest distance, and a second iteration to print all pairs with that distance. Optimization is good, but doesn't change the result.