# Jenkins groovy pipeline search and compare

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I need a solution for the following to work - search for value variable `BRANCHVERSION`  ​in `ver_list`, compare them and use an appropriate.

`BRANCHVERSION` has the format like this `"6.200.01"`​

`​ver_list`  looks like this

```
[Pipeline] echo
[6.000.02, 6.000.10, 6.000.12, 6.000.15, 6.000.20, 6.000.25, 6.000.30, 6.100.00, 6.100.01, 6.100.10, 6.100.20, 6.100.25, 6.100.30, 6.200.00, 6.300.00]
```

if  `BRANCHVERSION` is not equal to any values in `ver_list`, then​ the next closest value from the list ordered by descending must be picked up  ( if  `BRANCHVERSION` =   6.200.01, then 6.200.00 must be picked up)
if  `BRANCHVERSION` is equal to any values in `ver_list`, then that value is picked up.

**My pipeline described below:**

```
if (ENVIRONMENT == "") {
   error("You should choose at least one environment")
}
node {   
   deleteDir()
    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', locations: [[credentialsId: 'XXXXXXX',local: './env_prop_files', remote:'http://FQDN/repos/src/cm/env_prop_files']]])
    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', locations: [[credentialsId: 'XXXXXXX',local: './SoapUITestSuites', remote:'http://FQDN/repos/src/tools/SoapUI/branches/']]])
    def  FILES_LIST = sh (script: "ls   './SoapUITestSuites'", returnStdout:true).trim()
    def GS_LIST = sh (script: "ls 'path_to_file'", returnStdout: true).trim()
echo "GS_Version : ${GS_LIST}"
echo "FILES_LIST : ${FILES_LIST}"
//PARSING TestSuite Version
   def ver_list = []
     for(String ele : FILES_LIST.split("\\r?\\n")){ 
     ver = ele.split("_")
     println ">>>${ver[1]}<<<"     
     ver_list.add(ver[1])
}
println(ver_list)
def VERSION = ver_list
//PARSING GS Version
   def gs_list = []
    for(String elegs : GS_LIST.split("\\r?\\n")){ 
    println ">>>${elegs}<<<"     
    gs_list.add(elegs)
}  
println(gs_list) 
properties = readProperties file:"./env_prop_files/${ENVIRONMENT}.properties"
BRANCHVERSION = properties.SVN_LOCATION_VERSION
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
No changes for http://FQDN/repos/src/tools/SoapUI/branches since the previous 
build
[Pipeline] sh
[ClientRunSoapUITest] Running shell script
+ ls ./SoapUITestSuites
[Pipeline] sh
[ClientRunSoapUITest] Running shell script
+ ls /pkg/flexprod/oracle/flexprodfiles/archive/goldstand
[Pipeline] echo
GS_Version : 5.900.00
6.000.00
6.000.01
6.000.02
6.000.20
6.000.30
6.100.00
6.100.01
6.200.00
[Pipeline] echo
FILES_LIST : rel_6.000.02
rel_6.000.10
rel_6.000.12
rel_6.000.15
rel_6.000.20
rel_6.000.25
rel_6.000.30
rel_6.100.00
rel_6.100.01
rel_6.100.10
rel_6.100.20
rel_6.100.25
rel_6.100.30
rel_6.200.00
rel_6.200.01
rel_6.300.00
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.02<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.10<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.12<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.15<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.20<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.25<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.30<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.100.00<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.100.01<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.100.10<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.100.20<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.100.25<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.100.30<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.200.00<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.200.01<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.300.00<<<
[Pipeline] echo
[6.000.02, 6.000.10, 6.000.12, 6.000.15, 6.000.20, 6.000.25, 6.000.30, 6.100.00, 6.100.01, 6.100.10, 6.100.20, 6.100.25, 6.100.30, 6.200.00, 6.200.01, 6.300.00]
[Pipeline] echo
>>>5.900.00<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.00<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.01<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.02<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.20<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.000.30<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.100.00<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.100.01<<<
[Pipeline] echo
>>>6.200.00<<<
[Pipeline] echo
[5.900.00, 6.000.00, 6.000.01, 6.000.02, 6.000.20, 6.000.30, 6.100.00, 6.100.01, 6.200.00]
[Pipeline] readProperties
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
"6.200.01"
[Pipeline] lock
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all these are **strings** so you should c**hange them to double**. Much easier to compare them:  *6.200.21 becomes 6200,21* (or 6200.21 depending on your localization)

Keep them in a  list, it is much easier to work on them
The rest is simple Groovy List operations

```
BRANCH_VERSION = ver_list.contains(BRANCH_VERSION) ? BRANCH_VERSION : ver_list.max()
```

Of course if you need it as string then convert it back using the DecimalFormat Object and replace the commas with dots.

Comment: OP wanted the next closest number to the one specified so you will have to add a function to get the next closest value like this logic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13318733/get-closest-value-to-a-number-in-array

Comment: Right. I'm wondering if there is a more groovier way with lambda functions etc, like creating a delta list: `def deltas = ver_list.collect { (it - BRANCH_VERSION ).abs()}`. Afterwards you could get the next close item with `def closest_release = ver_list.filter { (it - BRANCH_VERSION).abs() == deltas.min()}.last()` aka the last(*Descending*) item having the smallest distance to the BRANCH_VERSION.
...
At the end, the expression is simplified to: `BRANCH_VERSION = ver_list.contains(BRANCH_VERSION) ? BRANCH_VERSION : closest_release`

Comment: Yup it's possible...Groovy uses Closures very similar to Lamda of Java

Comment: how I resolved this issue:
def versiongs = sh (script: "ls '/pkg/flexprod/oracle/flexprodfiles/archive/goldstand' | LC_ALL=C awk '\$0 <= ${BRANCHVERSION}' | xargs -n1 | sort -n | tail -1" , returnStdout: true).trim()
    echo "versiongs : ${versiongs}"
    def versionts = sh (script: "ls './SoapUITestSuites/branches' | awk -F_ '{print \$2}' | LC_ALL=C awk '\$0 <= ${BRANCHVERSION}' | xargs -n1 | sort -n | tail -1" , returnStdout: true).trim()
    echo "versionts : ${versionts}"